# Multiple Tailwind CSS config with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, config

I am building a Laravel app, and I want to create two tailwindcss config, and I can't figure it out how.

In `postcss.config.js` is defined:

```
tailwindcss: {
        config: './new-tailwindcss-config.js'
    },
```

I think `webpack.mix.js` in `require("tailwindcss")` use the config defined in `postcss.config.js`. But I don't got any exemple how can I add two config in `postcss.config.js`

```
.postCss("resources/assets/css/theme/tailwind.css", "public/css/theme", [
    require("tailwindcss"),
])
```

I am using the latest version of TailwindCSS (3.3.2v), and I know I can add `@config` to `tailwind.css`, but its also don't work for me, I always get an error like:

`The config file at "new-tailwind.config.js" does not exist. Make sure the path is correct and the file exists.`

Even if the config file is there and exist.

The `tailwind.css` file

```
@config "./new-tailwindcss-config.js"
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

But I think I need to modify the `postcss.config.js` somehow, or remove it. Or there is a way to define in `webpack.mix.js` which config to use? Any help would thanked.

Answer (score 2):

You can define 2 tailwind config using this code in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.postCss("resources/assets/css/theme/tailwind.css", "public/css/theme", [
    tailwindcss("tailwind-theme.config.js")
]);

mix.postCss("resources/assets/css/theme/tailwind2.css", "public/css/theme2", [
    tailwindcss("tailwind-theme2.config.js")
]);
```

You don't need `postcss.config.js` any more with this code and if you will need to add any additional postcss plugins you can add them like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.postCss("resources/assets/css/theme/tailwind.css", "public/css/theme", [
    tailwindcss("tailwind-theme.config.js"),
    require("postcss-import"),
]);

mix.postCss("resources/assets/css/theme/tailwind2.css", "public/css/theme2", [
    tailwindcss("tailwind-theme2.config.js"),
    require("postcss-import"),
]);
```